# Proof for a limit convergence of probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $\left \{ x_{n} \right \} $ be a sequence of random variables that converges in distribution to $X$ and $\left \{ y_{n} \right \}$ be a sequence of random variables such that

$\lim_{n \to \infty}\mathbb{P}(y_{n}>c)=1$ for any finite $c$

We are asked to prove that,for any finite $c$,

$\lim_{n \to \infty}\mathbb{P}(y_{n}+x_{n}>c)=1$

**My Approach**

The favourable region for $y_{n}+x_{n}>c$ lies above the line $\frac{X}{c}+\frac{Y}{c}=1$ in the 2-D Cartesian plane.

Let us call the set of values of $x$ and $y$ which satisfy this  as $A=\left\{(x,y):\frac{x}{c}+\frac{y}{c}>1\right\}$.

This region is larger than the region defined, for any finite $m$, by the points in $B=\left\{(x,y):x>m,y>c-m\right\}$

Hence using the above argument, for any fixed $m$, $\mathbb{P}(y_{n}+x_{n}>c)\geq \mathbb{P}(x_{n}>m,y_{n}>c-m)$

Using the fact that $\mathbb{P}(A\bigcap B)=\mathbb{P}(A)+ \mathbb{P}(A)- \mathbb{P}(A\bigcup B)$, we can write

$\mathbb{P}(x_{n}>m,y_{n}>c-m)=\mathbb{P}(x_{n}>m)+\mathbb{P}(y_{n}>c-m)-\mathbb{P}(U)$

Where $U$ is the region defined by the set of points
$U=\left\{(x,y):x>m \quad or\quad y>c-m\right\}$ also $\mathbb{P}(U)\leq1$

Using the above we have, for any fixed m,

$\mathbb{P}(y_{n}+x_{n}>c)\geq \mathbb{P}(x_{n}>m,y_{n}>c-m)= \mathbb{P}(x_{n}>m)+\mathbb{P}(y_{n}>c-m)-\mathbb{P}(U)
\geq \mathbb{P}(x_{n}>m)+\mathbb{P}(y_{n}>c-m)-1$

Using the first and last quantities in the inequality above,

$\mathbb{P}(y_{n}+x_{n}>c)\geq \mathbb{P}(x_{n}>m)+\mathbb{P}(y_{n}>c-m)-1$

Taking limit of n approaching $\infty$ on both sides

$\lim_{n \to \infty}\mathbb{P}(y_{n}+x_{n}>c)\geq\lim_{n \to \infty}\mathbb{P}(y_{n}>c-m)-\lim_{n \to \infty}(1- \mathbb{P}(x_{n}>m))\\= 
\lim_{n \to \infty}\mathbb{P}(y_{n}>c-m)-\lim_{n \to \infty}\mathbb{P}(x_{n} \leq m)$

The last part since $\left \{ x_{n} \right \} $ converges to $X$, we have

$\lim_{n \to \infty}\mathbb{P}(x_{n} \leq m)=\mathbb{P}(X \leq m)$

Hence, for any fixed $m$

$\lim_{n \to \infty}\mathbb{P}(y_{n}+x_{n}>c)\geq \lim_{n \to \infty}\mathbb{P}(y_{n}>c-m)-\mathbb{P}(X \leq m)$

As $m$  above is arbitrary, for any $\epsilon > 0$,chose an $m$ from the cumulative density function of $X$, such that $\mathbb{P}(X \leq m)=\frac{\epsilon}{2}$  **(statement A)**

Also since, for any finite $c$, $\lim_{n \to \infty}\mathbb{P}(y_{n}>c)=1$, we can say, using the definition of limit that for any $\epsilon$>0, we can find a $N$ such that for all $n>N$, the sequence of probabilities $P_{n} =\mathbb{P}(y_{n}>c)$ can be trapped as $1-\epsilon<P_{n}<1$

Using the above definition of limit, for a given $\epsilon$, we can find a $N$ such that for all $n>N$, the sequence of probabilities $P_{n}= \mathbb{P}(y_{n}>c-m) $ can be trapped as $1-\frac{\epsilon}{2}< P_{n}<1$ **(statement B)**

Combining statements A and B, for any $\epsilon>0$, we can find a $N$ such that for all $n>N$, the sequence of probabilities $p_{n}=\mathbb{P}(y_{n}+x_{n}>c)$ can be trapped as $\mathbb{P}(y_{n}+x_{n}>c)\geq 1-\epsilon$, hence  $\lim_{n \to \infty}\mathbb{P}(y_{n}+x_{n}>c)=1$

**My questions:**

Is the above reasoning correct for the given situation?

Is it necessary for $X$ to be continuous here?

Also I find it extremely difficult to envisage a sequence such that $\lim_{n \to \infty}\mathbb{P}(y_{n}>c)=1$ for any finite $c$

Any insights would be very helpful since it’s a bit difficult to conceptualise the situation here.